# SQL Server 2005 Management Studio - Recover Accidentally Closed Tab

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there a way to do this if an unsaved tab gets accidentally closed?

Comment: If the computer shutdown unexpectedly and you were not able to save the work then you may recover the files by going to `...\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files\Solution1` where it saves temporary files. True for SSMS 2008 R2 [more on this link](http://www.sqldbpros.com/2012/06/sql-server-management-studio-recover-lost-files/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. I checked on the msdn website and there's a thread about this and the answer is no.

Comment: Though not foolproof or guaranteed, check my answer below if you are really stuck and need to recover a query from an accidentally closed tab in the editor.

Comment: Check the answer below: SQL Server query cache helped me out.

Answer (score 24):

I was able to recover a query I was working on after accidentally closing the tab.  If you actually ran the query, it should be in SQL Server's query cache.  Query the query cache and order the results by creation date.  More info on the SQL Server query cache:

Modify a query like this one (found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=SQL.100).aspx)

```
SELECT cp.objtype AS PlanType,
       OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,st.dbid) AS ObjectName,
       cp.refcounts AS ReferenceCounts,
       cp.usecounts AS UseCounts,
       st.text AS SQLBatch,
       qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st;
```

to get your desired result.  The "st.text" column will have the query that was run on the database server.

Comment: Awesome idea! I don't know why this is not up-voted more. Saved me a whole lot of time re-writing a query after I got overly eager on cleaning up my open SSMS tabs.

Answer (score 4):

I also found at [MSDN website](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/ddcfbd4d-817a-46ec-893a-36f997a343fb/) that it is not possible to recover these files, but I would give a try to this (it worked for me):

1. Take a look in the folder C:\Users\YOURUSERIDHERE\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files\Solution1 and choose files for date when machine restarted or crash happened. [SQLBlog.com](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/07/19/recover-backed-up-query-files-in-sql-server-management-studio.aspx)
2. Take a look in the folder C:\Users\”[your username goes here]“\AppData\Local\Temp\ (this wasn't work for me because my .sql files had 0KB and .tmp files had something, but I couldn't find the way to 'extract' code from these .tmp files). Suppose that sometimes can be helpful,  depending on reason of system reboot/crash. [ayesamson.com](http://ayesamson.com/2011/10/21/recovering-unsaved-or-modified-scripts/)

Comment: I just want to add that it's not necessarily `C:\Users\YOURUSERIDHERE\Documents`, it's wherever your My Documents folder resides. On some systems My Documents is redirected to another location. Otherwise, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that there is, but using [TimeSnapper](http://www.timesnapper.com/) can be a help to show what was previously in the window.

Comment: Interesting concept, this TimeSnapper.  I'm afraid not magical enough to work post-facto, i.e. this tools would have needed to be running [in the background] at the time the OPs' tab got closed accidentally...

Comment: Unfortunately not. That would be a good feature though, I'll suggest it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to My Documents\SQL Server Management Studio Express\Backup Files\Solution1 you will find the Recovered backlogs.This is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.Take a look in the folder C:\Users\YOURUSERIDHERE\AppData\Local\temp, then sort files by date modified and pick the last .sql that has a size greater than 0 bytes. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SSMS currently does not have the Undo Closed Tab feature.  I have created the following Connect Item so Microsoft will hopefully add this in a future version: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1044403